# Can't access <img> to change it's src with on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to do a function in a "game of life" that will change a cell to living or dead on click depending on it's previous state. Seems pretty easy and it probably is but sometimes you're stuck and for whatever reason you can't find that easy solution.

The main problem is that I can't access only one clicked `img` and `click()` function only works with area div (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pWSL.jpg).

Obviously I've searched the internet and tried many different versions of code but nothing is working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        simulatorInit();
        $("#area").click(function()
    {
        alert("dasd");

    });
});
```

That is what I have now and it alerts when I click on the "board" but I dunno how to access specific "clicked" img.

Tried something like this but it doesn't work either:

```
$(this).click(function()
    {
        if($("div").attr('src','dead.gif')) $(this).attr('src','alive.gif')

    });
});
```

Edit:: html code:

```
    <div id="areaWrapper">
        <div id="area" class="ui-corner-all">
            Aby rozpocząć wygeneruj plansze
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Okienko panelu kontrolnego -->
    <div id="controls">
        <label for="area-x">Szerokość</label>
        <input id="area-x" value="10" type="number" min="3" /><br/>
        <label for="area-y">Wysokość</label>
        <input id="area-y" value="10" type="number" min="3" /><br/>
        <button id="generate-area-button">Generuj plansze</button>
        <hr/>
        <label for="live-prob">Szansa na losowe życie</label>
        <input id="live-prob" value="0.4" type="number" min="0.01" max="1" step="0.01" /><br/>
        <button id="random-area-button">Losuj</button>
        <hr/>
        <label for="speed">Szybkość w ms</label>
        <input id="speed" value="600" type="number" min="40" step="10" /><br/>
    </div>
    <!-- Pasek narzędziowy -->
    <div id="bar" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        Krok:<span id="step">0</span>
        <button id="play-pause-button">Zatrzymaj/Wznów</button>
        <button id="show-panel-button">Pokaż panel</button>
    </div>
```

and generating cells:

```
function generateArea(){
                var x = parseInt($("#area-x").val());
                var y = parseInt($("#area-y").val());
                $('#area').html('');
                for(var i=0;i<y;i++){
                    for(var j=0;j<x;j++){
                        var img=$("<img />");
                        img.attr("src",dead);
                        img.attr("cell-x",j);
                        img.attr("cell-y",i);
                        img.addClass("cell");
                        $('#area').append(img);
                    }
                    $('#area').append($('<br/>'));
                }
            }
```

Comment: please post your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't binding the click handler to the images, only to the parent `<div>`.

Also `if($("div").attr('src','dead.gif'))` is not doing what you think. It is actually setting the attribute to `dead.gif` each time. It should be more like `if($("div").attr('src') === 'dead.gif'))`

Try

```
$('#area img').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, existingSrc){
       return existingSrc === 'dead.gif' ? 'alive.gif' : 'dead.gif';
    });
});
```

Comment: Did u mean to write $('$area img') or whouldn't it be $('#area img')? But it didn't work anyway

Comment: Oh yes  should be `#` not `$`...fixed in answer

Comment: i also tried that only with alert but it still can't alert the src and again no errors

Comment: Yeah, i understand it should work but for me it still desn't, if i change to just #area it shows alert and with img it doesn't. I was thinking that maybe the img is somehow blocked but when i use select element on the page in f12 on chrome and click on cell it shows me the img in elements properly.

Comment: Try changing to : `$('#area').on('click', 'img',  function(){...`. If images are added **after** my code in answer runs it won't find them but using this delegation approach will

Comment: Well I think i somehow found what is the problem. It is the path to img because now ( i kinda solved my original problem) when i want to check if cell has dead or alive gif i would need to do if with full path not just == "alive.gif" and  i wonder why is that ( i obviously have those files in same folder as html)

Answer (score 0):

The `event.target` has the specific `img` info. Refer the jQuery API page: https://api.jquery.com/event.target/